# get_posts only displaying a link to homepage

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I'm developing my first Wordpress theme and the first loop I have is only outputting 1 item: a link to the homepage (not any of the arguments I am trying to pass in the array).

Here's the php and html:

```
<div class="services_list">         
    <?php 
        $args = array(
            'posts_per_page'=>  999,
            'orderby'       =>  'menu_order',
            'order'         =>  'ASC',
            'post_type'     =>  'service',
            'meta_key'      =>  'featured',
            'meta_value'    =>  '1'
        );
    // The Query
    get_posts( $args );
    // The Loop
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <div class="service_item">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" class="service_top_link">
                <div class="service_image"><?php the_post_thumbnail( array(120,120) ); ?></div>
            </a>
            <h3 class="service_title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
            <div class="service_excerpt"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="Learn More" class="learn_more" role="button">Learn More</a>
        </div><!-- .service_item -->
    <?php endwhile;
        // Reset Query
        wp_reset_query();
    ?>
</div><!-- .services_list -->
```

I apologize if this question has already been answered, but I can't seem to find anything on it.

Comment: For secondary loops you should use [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query). See http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1755/38742 for an explanation on when to use what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

worked! thanks. I switched from get_posts to using WP_query and was having the same problem. Turns out the issue was actually with the meta value, not the query itself.